# Remove zeros from country code of phone number in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsstring, phone-number, country-codes

I want to remove the preceding zeros from phone number's country code. 
I take it as NSString because phone number contains symbols such as + , ( , ) , - .
I need those symbols.

e.g

Input:-

```
1) NSString *phNo = @"0011234567890";
2) NSString *phNo2 = @"0601234567999";
```

Output:-

```
1) 11234567890
2) 601234567999
```

What I did is as follows

```
if ([phNo length]>10) {
        NSString *countryCodeSubString = [phNo substringToIndex:[phNo length]-10];
        if ([[countryCodeSubString substringToIndex:1]isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            for (int i=0; i<[countryCodeSubString length]; i++) {
                NSString *str = [countryCodeSubString substringToIndex:i];
                if ([str isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
                    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@""];
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I know above code is wrong. 
Can anybody help me with this ? How can I do this efficiently ?

Comment: You may want to use `hasPrefix` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int firstNonZeroCharIndex = -1;
for (int i=0; i<phNo.length; ++i) {
    if ([phNo.characterAtIndex:i] != '0') {
        firstNonZeroCharIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (firstNonZeroCharIndex != -1) {
    phNo = [phNo subStringFromIndex:firstNonZeroCharIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the preceding zeroes off, then you can do simply like this.

```
NSString *phNo = @"0011234567890";
float number = [phNo floatValue];
NSString *phNoWithOutZero = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f", number];
```

But this will not work it the string have any special characters except number.

Comment: Your solution also works. But I have symbols in string. Anyway thanks.
I tried below code previously , but it outputs worng . Can you tell me whats wrong in it ? Here is my code

`NSString *phNo = @"0011234567890";
NSLog(@"Ph No : %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[phNo intValue]]);`

Output :-
Ph No : 2147483647

Why its not working ?

Comment: Int values are limited to 8 bytes (–2147483648 to 2147483647). So if the number is greater than 2147483647 it will take it as 2147483647.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Common%20long%20integer%20sizes

Comment: Thanks suresh... I just missed that limit part.